# Laravel using UIkit

Tags: laravel-5, uikit, laravel-elixir

I've created new project on my local XAMPP server using composer

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel ad dev-develop
```

then I installed UIkit via composer

```
composer require uikit/uikit
```

and I got UIkit in `vendor` folder in my project
[image]

But I don't understand what should I do next? How to compile `uikit.less` in css file and which folder should I use to keep my css files ?

Comment: `composer require` was your mistake - uikit should be delivered via npm or bower. so your first step would be something like `npm install uikit` - then it will get added to your node dependencies. Then you can pull it in using Mix/Elixir/Webpack/Gulp/Grunt or what ever you want to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your final `css` files somewhere in `public` directory, for example `public/css`.

To achieve that you should have for example installed `npm` and `gulp`, now you can in `gulpfile.js` write something like that:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
    mix.less('uikit.less');
});
```

And now when you run `gulp` it will create `uikit.css` file in `public/css` directory. You should read about [Laravel Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#introduction) to understand what is happening here.

You should also make sure you really want to use `dev-develop` branch of Laravel instead of `master`.

**EDIT**

If your less files is in different directory you should do something like this:

```
elixir(function (mix) {
     mix.less('../../../here-you-put-rest-of-path/uikit.less');
});
```

so in your case path should be something like this:

```
../../../vendor/uikit/uikit/src/less/uikit.less
```

because default directory is `resources/assets/less` and in case you want to use custom directory you need to use `../` to go out of this directory and use your custom directory (absolute path seems to not work)

Comment: The problem is, gulp is trying to find UIkit in resourses folder http://i.stack.imgur.com/hiITr.png But composer installs it in vendor folder.

Comment: Use `..` to go up directories. So `../../../vendor/uikit/themes/default/uikit.less`, or something to that effect. I don't have an example in front of me so I don't know for sure that will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used `../../../vendor/uikit/uikit/src/less/uikit.less` path and now gulp works just fine. Actually I still don't understand why composer installs UIkit in vendor folder instead of resources folder, in my mind, it's some kind of weird.

Comment: @Heidel This is how composer works. Everything is put into `vendor` directory.

Comment: You are skipping the fact that you'll likely need at least some of the JS in the library, as well.

Answer (score 1):

For people having similar questions in 2019 and beyond, I have made a Laravel 6-compatible package that will set up a UIkit and Vue.js boilerplate site, in place of the default Bootstrap version.

https://github.com/Torrix/laravel-ui-uikit

[image: Screenshot of UIkit running in Laravel]

Comment: Thank you, I will use in my app.